# Wireshark doesn't capture on interface wlan0mon

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, monitoring, tshark

I am using Wireshark to scan for unwanted traffic in my home network. I enabled monitor mode for `wlan0` using:

```
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

When I check `iwconfig` I can see the `wlan0mon` interface which has monitor mode enabled. When I start a capture with `tshark -I -i wlan0mon`, the scan runs but doesn't capture anything. I check this by using another device which is on the same network at the same time.

I cannot find my mistake, but maybe someone of you knows what's wrong here.

Comment: Have you set your wireless interface that's in monitor mode to the same channel as the target network?

Comment: How can I check this? :)

Comment: do you know what channel your network is on (e.g. in your WiFi router settings), or use `airodump-ng` to scan all networks. Then, set the interface's channel using `iw` (the "newer" `iwconfig`) using `iw dev wlan0mon set channel <channel>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I checked the channel of my router, which is 6, changed it, but still tshark doesn't capture anything. I noticed that airodump-ng doesn't find the wlan router at all.

Comment: @PatZio It's better to capture using `airodump-ng` and then opening that capture file with wireshark

Comment: Are you using windows? You need either winpcap or npcap installed (depending on wireshark version) to allow windows to monitor traffic.